# `print("Hello, World!")`

Tags: polyomino, jigsaw-puzzle

Build `HELLO`. Only rotations, no reflections.

[image]

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244176/negative-of-an-ascii-photo/244180#244180

Comment: Input and output 3

Comment: Great find!!!!!

Comment: I found it trying to solve blue herrings puzzle 

Comment: link (to pzl) thnx?

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125059/yes-but-where-am-i

Answer (score 45, accepted):

... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...

---

> [image]

---

Comment: naq gur artngvir fcnpr fcryyf bhg URYYB!!!